# I can only access local webpage on browsers using the ip address instead of hostname.local

Tags: networking, dns, ip, raspberry-pi, home-networking

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 and I set up pi-hole on it. The local IP address of the raspberry pi is 192.168.1.52 and its hostname is "homepi".

From my mac I can ping and ssh into the pi using either its ip or its hostname.
Further when I do nslookup I get the expected results:

```
nslookup homepi
Server:     192.168.1.1
Address:    192.168.1.1#53

Name:   homepi.broadband
Address: 192.168.1.52
```

```
nslookup 192.168.1.52
Server:     192.168.1.1
Address:    192.168.1.1#53

52.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa   name = homepi.broadband.
```

I can only access the pi-hole webpage when typing "192.168.1.52" into a browser.
When I type "homepi.broadband", I get an error message: `No web page was found for the web address: http://homepi.broadband/`

However I noticed that I can access my router settings webpage by either going to "192.168.1.1" or typing in "vodafone.broadband" on any browser.

I have checked if it is an issue with not having a Static DHCPv4, so I assigned it a static IPv4 address (192.168.1.52) via my router settings webpage but it still did not work.

So how can I access local webpages using the "hostname.local" or "hostname.broadband" format instead of typing in the ip address into the browser?

I am not sure if this is an issue with my router or my raspberry pi. I also checked using a Windows laptop and I get the same results, so I don't think this is an issue with my mac.

Edit this is the hosts file from my mac.

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Comment: Do you have multiple DNS servers configured on macOS?

Comment: @user1686 No, just the default one.

Comment: I also checked with a browser on a windows laptop and I got the same results.

Comment: @Shree - Post your hosts file from your laptop. Is your laptop DNS set to 192.168.1.1?

Comment: `.local` is special and uses mDNS. `nslookup` (and other TLDs) do not. I suggest you focus your question on one way.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes DNS is set to 192.168.1.1, and I added the hosts file in the post.

Comment: You need to add homepi.broadband to your hosts file

Comment: @Ramhound I considered that, but that would only solve the problem for this particular device right? I am looking for a network level solution where it would work on any browser on any device on the network, like how it works with my router webpage "vodafone.broadband"

Comment: does your router allow you to configure a DNS zone? if so I'd recommend creating your own domain name for your LAN (eg foo.net or whatever) that does not use either .local or .broadband, and create entries for each of the systems you wish to name. then you wouldn't need to worry about multicast DNS being unreliable and it will work across all your devices with no additional config beyond pointing your systems DNS server to your pihole in the routers DHCP configuration.

Comment: @Shree - `vodafone.broadband` works because the router's hosts file contains an entry for `vodafone.broadband`, and since your router is providing the DNS to your network, that is the reason it works.